# Which Java EE container works for Apache Camel/CXF/ActiveMQ web applications using EJBs?

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, activemq-classic, ejb-3.1, apache-servicemix

The Camel web page says

*The following projects can leverage Apache Camel as a routing and mediation engine:
Apache ServiceMix - a popular distributed open source ESB and JBI container
Apache ActiveMQ - a mature, widely used open source message broker
Apache CXF - a smart web services suite (JAX-WS and JAX-RS)
Apache Karaf - a small OSGi based runtime in which applications can be deployed
Apache MINA - a high-performance NIO-driven networking framework*

However, I would like to run Camel inside a Java EE web application and have access to web services, JMS, and EJB (CDI, message driven beans, JPA, etc.)  Preferably using an open source Java EE server.

If I recommend this to my company, then then all the usual Java EE wizards such as wsdl2java need to work out of the box. There also needs to be documentation and tutorials so we can hire people to jump in and start using it.

Glassfish failed across the board. The wsdl2java wizard for CXF fails using the Glassfish runtime classes (I ran it manually and hacked my code tree.) There is no documentation nor any tutorials for wiring in OpenMQ (and google searches on the topic are discouraging.) Simple library-only samples run fine, of course, but without having ActiveMQ as the native JMS it seems to be a dead end. CXF integration seems unworkable as well. My first attempt at copying a WS sample complains "No component found with scheme: cxf" which appears to be a bundle or classpath issue.

I'm starting to think I should go back to ServiceMix and drop back to servlets without EJBs and CDI, even though I really hated not being able to use Eclipse gracefully for edit/compile/debug (you pretty much have to build and run from an outside DOS prompt window and remote debug in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Camel with any container of choice. We try to not have any restrictions or barriers. You can also run it standalone. The web page just mentions some of the containers you can use.

Apache Camel is just a bunch of JAR files you can deploy and use in any container of choice. For example with WAR files you can deploy to Tomcat, TomEE, etc.

Comment: I see I left something out, sorry. I want to use CXF with ActiveMQ and so I run into conflicts with what is already installed in the JEE container. I also ran into classloader conflicts with just Camel on one of them. I suppose my issue has more to do with this aspect of choosing a JEE container than it has to do with Camel pe se.

Comment: I am changing the question.